# What is the meaning of "Abkettrand"?

Tags: translation, single-word-request, meaning, technical-terminology

I believe ***"Abkettrand"*** is a knitting term of some description but have been unable to find a translation to English. Here is a sample paragraph where it's appeared:

> Zum Schluss die letzte Masche mit Nähgarn am Abkettrand festnähen, den
>   Faden auf ca. 4 cm Länge zurückschneiden, einen 2 cm breiten Saum
>   arbeiten, den Saum zusammen ziehen und am Abkettrand festnähen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *Abkettrand* is the bind-off, i.e. the result of the binding off or casting off the stitches of the last knitting row.

Answer (score 3):

In textile manufacturing a fringe (German *"Rand, Saum"*) of a fabric is tucked with a special stitch: it is *chained off*. This literally translates to German "[abketteln](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketteln)".

Hence the *"Abkettrand*" is a composite noun built from *"abketteln"* and *"Rand"*, i.e. it is the *fringe to be chained off*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't knit, but it appears it's referring to the edge or border (Rand) of the last group of knitted loops or chains formed as you wrap the yarn around the finger or knitting needle (abketteln) and pull it back through, or whatever (like I say, I don't knit, lol). Your paragraph describes how to finish off putting a seam on the cloth to finish tying off the loops.

So, I guess the literal English for "Abkettrand" would be something like "chain edge or border". Perhaps there's a more precise knitting word in English for what the loops and chains are called.